# Using lxml to parse text and break it into a list of sentences using some tags to add structure

Tags: python, parsing, lxml, elementtree

Consider the following text in custom `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <heading><b>This is a title</b></heading>
    <p>This is a first <b>paragraph</b>.</p>
    <p>This is a second <b>paragraph</b>. With a list: 
        <ul>
            <li>first item</li>
            <li>second item</li>
        </ul>
    And the end.
    </p>
    <p>This is a third paragraph.
        <ul>
            <li>This is a first long sentence.</li>
            <li>This is a second long sentence.</li>
        </ul>
    And the end of the paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

I would like to convert that in a list of plain strings with the following rules:

- Discard some tags like `<b></b>`
- Each `heading` and each `paragraph` are distinct elements in the list. Add a final period if missing at the end of the element.
- When a list is preceded by a colon ":", just add a line break between elements and add dashes.
- When a list is not preceded by a colon, act as if the paragraph was split into several paragraphs

The result would be:

```
[
    "This is a title.", # Note the period
    "This is a first paragraph.",
    "This is a second paragraph. With a list:\n- first item\n- second item\nAnd the end.",
    "This is a third paragraph.",
    "This is a first long sentence.",
    "This is a second long sentence.",
    "And the end of the paragraph."
]
```

I would like to do that by iterating on the result of the lmxl etree `etree.fromstring(text)`. My first few trials are overly complicated and slow, and I'm sure there is a nice approach to this problem.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting exercise...

The following is a bit convoluted and won't give you the exact output you indicated, but maybe it'll be close enough for you (or someone else) to modify it:

```
from lxml import etree
stuff = """[your xml]"""
        
doc =  etree.XML(stuff)
    
#we need this in order to count how many <li> elements meet the condition
#in your xml there are only two, but this will take care of more elements
comms = len(doc.xpath('//p[contains(.,":")]//ul//li'))
final = []
    
for t in doc.xpath('//*'):
    line = "".join(list(t.itertext()))    
    allin = [l.strip() for l in line.split('\n  ') if len(l.strip())>0]
    for l in allin:
        ind = allin.index(l)
        for c in range(comms):
            if ":" in allin[ind-(c+1)]:
                final.append("- "+l)
        if l[-1] =="." or l[-1] ==":":
            final.append(l)
        else:
            if not ("- "+l in final):
                final.append(l+".")
    break
 
final
```

Output:

```
['This is a title.',
 'This is a first paragraph.',
 'This is a second paragraph. With a list:',
 '- first item',
 '- second item',
 'And the end.',
 'This is a third paragraph.',
 'This is a first long sentence.',
 'This is a second long sentence.',
 'And the end of the paragraph.']
```